# Conversion of clockwise angle rotation to anticlockwise and vice versa

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors, rotations, mathematica

I have some data sets and using that data sets I'm trying to calculate the rotation numbers. Calculating rotation numbers I have to take some particular direction of vectors, i.e., either clockwise or anticlockwise. I'm able to do clockwise orientation. But facing difficulty with anti-clockwise orientation. Could anyone please help me with this?  I'm pasting my code here

```
centralPoint = {24.21472610092954`, 
  3.5934127487768646`*^-6}; seqOfAng = 
 Table[initialPoint = Xdata[[i]]; subsequentPoint = Xdata[[i + 1]]; 
  v1 = Simplify[initialPoint - centralPoint];
  v2 = Simplify[subsequentPoint - centralPoint];
  unitVector1 = v1/Norm[v1];
  unitVector2 = v2/Norm[v2];
  (* A positive determinant between two vectors means that the angles \
have an anti-clock wise orientation. So, 
  we impose the condition that if the angle is in anti-clock wise, 
  the angle should be changed in clock wise direction. *)
  angle = 
   If[Det[{v1, v2}] >= 0, 
    N[2 Pi - VectorAngle[unitVector1, unitVector2]], 
    N[VectorAngle[unitVector1, unitVector2]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[Xdata] - 1, 1}]; rotNum = N[Mean[seqOfAng]/(2 Pi )]
```

Using different data sets I got the plot [for clockwise rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPwtU.png)
But I want the plot like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnDDd.png). So maybe this is due to the different direction of anlge rotation.

Can anyone please help me with this? How to calculate all angles in a counter-clockwise direction?
Does the plot have opposite direction if we have all angles in opposite directions?

I'm not able to add the data set here. Can I add at least one data set here? How to add?

Comment: What unit of angular measurement are you using???? Because if you change direction you just replace $\theta$ with $-\theta$. Or because (radian) angles don't care if you add or subtract $2 \pi$, you can use $2\pi + (-\theta)$. But your graphs show a value of about 0.32 for $x=5$, and you say that should be about 0.21 in the second graph. I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: thanks, @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC. I'm using angles in radians.

Comment: The two plots that I have posted are just for direction. They don't have exactly the same data. But, here I'm just asking about the direction. What if we change the directions of angles, will the direction of the plot change?

Comment: From the data set, first I'm making two vectors, then calculating the angle between two vectors, the angle could be clockwise or anticlockwise, but I want to take only one direction. I mean if I choose a clockwise direction then anticlockwise angles should be changed into clockwise. Similiarly, if I choose anticlockwise direction, then clockwise angles should be converted to anticlockwise. For clockwise I'm using the condition `angle = 
   If[Det[{v1, v2}] >= 0, 
    N[2 Pi - VectorAngle[unitVector1, unitVector2]], 
    N[VectorAngle[unitVector1, unitVector2]]]`

Comment: How this condition will be changed if I have to choose anticlockwise direction.

Comment: It's already written in your code: $\theta_{\text{anticlockwise}}=2\pi-\theta_{\text{clockwise}}$.

Comment: Thank you @Intelligentipauca. got it!